# Android Wear screen sizes

Tags: java, android, wear-os

At present the resolution of Android wear devices is:
280x280 or 
320x320

Does anyone know if you should have graphics for both the screen sizes and place them under the hdpi and xhdpi folders?

Also is there a way to auto scale down your images from 320x320 so that they work on a 280x280 device?

Thanks!

Comment: [320x320 uses hdpi as well](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/platforms.html)

Comment: @rmoh21 have you found answer on your question, maybe you can help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56698943/android-wear-os-watch-face-support-different-screen-sizes

Comment: @ViktorApoyan - so what I did was have images at a larger resolution say - 1080x1080 and then prgorammatically scale them down depending on the screen size at hand. Hacky but worked. Use compressed images as best as you can. I have been out of this for almost 4 years so sorry if I cant provide more details around it but hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. hdpi should be all that you need, all watches are a hdpi density
2. I would create background images at 320x320 and android will automatically scale them down to 280x280 if needed.
3. You will need to watch out for round devices, as they are 320x320 but the corners will be cut off

Comment: maybe you can help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56698943/android-wear-os-watch-face-support-different-screen-sizes